# Elastic Search how do you remove object property using painless

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

Wondering if anybody knows why this **update by query** runs fine but nothing gets deleted even though task runs to completion and claims all records are updated? I can use the same syntax to delete all **person** objects without any issues. Why does ES not delete object properties?

```json
POST /16cf303e902f4445a560a8e9a5b9ea51/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed&wait_for_completion=false
{
  
  "conflicts": "proceed",
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "person.hair_color"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._source.remove('person.hair_color');"
  }
}
```

Now if I watch the task using the ID returned from the above call

> GET /_tasks/qLeuj8jqQgOPFGsEzL7u9Q:1776664

I get this (shorted version) claiming all documented were updated. However all person's still have their hair color for some reason.

```json
{
  "completed" : true,
  "task" : {
    "status" : {
      "updated" : 110345,
     }
}
```

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out finally! Apparently the **_source** contains all objects in your document. Therefore to delete an object property you need to run:

```json
POST /16cf303e902f4445a560a8e9a5b9ea51/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed&wait_for_completion=false
{
  
  "conflicts": "proceed",
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "person.hair_color"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._source.person.remove('hair_color');"
  }
}
```

> This works if anybody has the same issue!